# Finding the distribution and density function of $Y = \log X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let's $X$ be a random variable with exponential distribution.
That means that:

1. $F_X(t) = 1 - e^{1- \lambda t}$ which is the distribution function for $X$,
2. $f_X(t) = \lambda e^{- \lambda t}$ which is the density function for $X$.

Now let's define another random variable $Y = \log X$. Our task is to find it's distribution and density function.

---

#### My attempt

Firstly I want to find the distribution function:
$$F_{y}(t) := P(Y < t) = P(\log X < t) = P(X < e^t) = \int\limits_{0}^{e^t} \lambda e^{- \lambda x} \mbox{d}x$$
$$F_Y(t) = 1 - e^{- \lambda e^{t}}$$
Here's my question: how do I know what the integration limits should be? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Distribution of $X$ is $1-e^{\lambda t} $, for $t>0$. $F_Y(t)=1-e^{\lambda e^t}$

Comment: I'd add that we can take $\log$ of $X$ because $P(X\leq 0)=0$. You know what integration limits are, because you know distribution function of $X$. Notice that $P(X<e^t)=F_X(e^t)$. Reasoning is overall ok

Comment: @Adam Thank you! So in general the limits will be given by the function $F_X(t)$ for any random variable $X$?

Comment: If $Y=\log X$ like here, then it will be analogous

Comment: @Adam Thank you! One more question: what can I say about the expected value of $\log X$?

Comment: You can calculate it from this $\mathbb{E}(\log X) = \int_\mathbb{R_+} \log(x) f_X(x) dx $

Comment: @Adam Thanks! If the integral value will be below zero that would mean that $Y$ has no expected value?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $R_+$

Comment: @Adam Thank you! So $Y$ has expected value and it's well defined by the integral you've written, yes?

Comment: It's an equality, such that if one side exists, the other one does too. So to check if it has expected value, you need to check if the integral exists

Comment: @Adam I think I understand it now. So I have to calculated the given integral (according to Wolfram it does exist). Thus $Y$ has an expected value?